# C: implementing a Sha512 encryption with crypt(3)

Tags: c, encryption

As the title is saying I want to implement a simple Sha512 encryption with the C function crypt(3).

I have pretty much copied the examplecode from the GNU, even though I know the salt calculation isn`t very good. Also I changed the $1$ to the $6$, since the manpage of crypt says that this would create an SHA512 hash.

Anyway the output seems very strange to me, so I am asking if there is anything wrong with my code:

This is pretty much the function:

```
static char* hashStr(char *str) {
    unsigned long seed[2];
    char salt[] = "$6$........";
    const char *const seedchars =
    "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"
    "UVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    seed[0] = time(NULL);
    seed[1] = getpid() ^ (seed[0] >> 14 & 0x30000);

    // Turn it into printable characters from `seedchars'.
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        salt[3+i] = seedchars[(seed[i/5] >> (i%5)*6) & 0x3f];
    }
    return crypt(str, salt);
}
```

Heres some output:

```
Bro  -> $6$9AcWGmwG$5faOmA7QpXQ/MMmbFAT085HraONeaMYlTcBg09WmQUpSI.PkcrcDQiXCetyjuIK3sr3H5cIFyxHD.fywr9UfY/

Homie -> $6$BAcWGnwG$KUPLOdpa8QgF.cVljBXYl62lL9zejDW/ZWENUoC90jO4NinNc1Itk7Z1Zo3myogmHR/YPwoc2cqfjBL0cf.Ht0

hey -> $6$IAcWGowG$47WGhO6Hco9DOc0rnxu/KEttLvjv4wH6vJX8qj6hALr0Wa1/YQb0JETEcRgpe9.cPvwOBjQduLZn17gwSXM86.
```

What makes me wonder if the output is legit is especially that theres this &6& at the beginning every time.

Comment: `salt[3+i]`that's why you keep the `&6&` at the beginning.

Comment: yeah the &6& at the beginning is needed for crypt(3) to determine which kind of hash algorithm should be used, but I find it a bit strange that it is also in the output.

Comment: Where did you get the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html#NOTES) crypt(3) return:

```
$id$salt$encrypted
```

That's why you get `$6$8chars$...`

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. So basically that means my code is alright.